# SwiftUI - Horizontal ScrollView locks up when transitioning from the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, transition, swiftui

Essentially, whenever I attempt to transition a horizontally scrolling ScrollView using `AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom)` the app freezes, and memory keeps going up. I've managed to reproduce the issue in the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showScroll: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showScroll = true
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Hit me")
            }).padding()
                .background(Capsule().fill())
            Spacer()
            if showScroll {
                scrollView
            }
        }
    }

    var scrollView: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                Text("Horizontal list")
                Text("Horizontal list")
                Text("Horizontal list")
                Text("Horizontal list")
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
    }
}
```

Changing the ScrollView axis to `.vertical` prevents the app from hanging, as does changing the transition to a different edge (e.g. `.leading`).

Has anyone else come across anything like this?

Comment: confirmed for 13.2, works in 13.0 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure HStack.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showScroll: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showScroll = true
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Hit me")
            }).padding()
                .background(Capsule().fill())
            Spacer()
            if showScroll {
                scrollView
            }
        }
    }

    var scrollView: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                Text("Horizontal list")
                Text("Horizontal list")
                Text("Horizontal list")
                Text("Horizontal list")
            }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up also needing to set the `minHeight`, but this did indeed fix the issue. Thank you

Comment: A height of 100 (on the `ScrollView`) was too high for my needs and found that anything below 50 would still freeze the app.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)`
 instead of `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` gave me better results. ie . I could set any value for `.frame(height: 100)` and it would not freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm described behaviour in Simulator, in Preview all is ok. Xcode 11.2. Wrapping in VStack like below fixes the issue.

```
var scrollView: some View {
    VStack {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                Text("Horizontal list")
                Text("Horizontal list")
                Text("Horizontal list")
                Text("Horizontal list")
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
    }
    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
}
```

Comment: While you're technically right that wrapping it in a VStack fixes the app hanging, it's effectively the same as removing the transition completely since the VStack itself doesn't have a transition so uses the default.

Comment: It just needed to move transition to VStack